# telegram user phone number or id in dialogflow webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram

I have integration DialogFlow vs Telegram.

I am sending webhook at fullfilment.

How can i get user Telegram phone number and send it at webhook?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get phone number from Telegram Bot API but you can extract user id. This is example payload you will receive in webhook (in request['originalDetectIntentRequest']['payload'] node):

```
{  
   'source':'telegram',
   'data':{  
      'update_id':123456789.0,
      'message':{  
         'from':{  
            'is_bot':False,
            'username':'user_name',
            'id':123456789.0,
            'language_code':'pl',
            'last_name':'Last Name',
            'first_name':'First Name'
         },
         'chat':{  
            'type':'private',
            'last_name':'Last Name',
            'id':123456789.0,
            'first_name':'First Name',
            'username':'user_name'
         },
         'message_id':258.0,
         'text':'user message',
         'date':1564341923.0
      }
   }
}
```

The only way to get user's phone number is to ask him. You can find more information here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro#locations-and-numbers